# What does “Muslim clockmakers” mean in “He (Trump) vowed to take back the country from Muslim clockmakers?

Tags: meaning

Today’s (Sept. 19) New Yorker carries an article titled “Poll: Guy who asked Trump Muslim question leads G.O.P. race,” which quoted Donald Trump’s assertion - “If you look back over the past seven years, no one has called Obama a foreign-born Muslim more often than I have.”

The article wraps up with the following lines:

> “Trump’s comments did little to slow the momentum of Muslim Question
>   Guy, who drew four thousand people at his first official campaign
>   rally in Concord, New Hampshire, where he vowed to take back the
>   country from **Muslim clockmakers**.”
>   http://www.newyorker.com/humor/borowitz-report/poll-guy-who-asked-trump-muslim-question-leads-g-o-p-race?

What does “Muslim clockmakers” specifically mean? Is there any particular reason for being clockmakers? Why not any other trades, say smith, mill owners, merchants, or farmers?

Comment: A kid named [Ahmed Mohammed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahmed_Mohamed_(student)) made an electronic clock and brought it in to school to show his teacher. Another teacher reported him to the police, believing the complex-looking clock was a bomb. The kid was arrested, and later released. It's big news here in the US (the liberals call it racial profiling, the conservatives call it race-baiting / outrage-peddling).

Comment: (Also worth mentioning this is just the scandal of the week. Few months from now, you won't see politicians making references to clockmakers.)

Comment: The above is the only reference to "Muslim clockmakers" I've seen anywhere.

Comment: ＠Dan Bron. If it is the case, isn’t the use of ‘clockmaker’ overstretched, even if it's a joke? Why should a group of all adult people represented by the Moslem question guy should vow to take back the America from a teen-age clockmaker who was innocent, or clockmakers alike? It sounds childish and really absurd than a pro-wrestler who vows to squarely wrestle with a baby for a teddy bear.

Comment: @YoichiOishi The guy in question is a right-wing nut. He initially drew attention to himself through interaction with Donald Trump, who is precisely, as you so aptly put it, *absurd*. But... if you want a slightly more substantial explanation: this guy is using "Muslim clockmakers" as synecdoche for everything he sees wrong with America and its press. He wants to take the country back from more than a kid with a clock, he wants to take it back from everyone who is making such a big deal about a kid with a clock (and not making a big enough deal about stuff he cares about).

Comment: @YoichiOishi It's sarcasm. He's ridiculing Trump and his followers for being afraid of people like this teenager.

Comment: The Borowitz Report is satire, and generally very well-crafted satire.  @YoichiOishi is definitely not the first to be taken in!  At times I wish that it were more clearly identified as satire, but that would ruin the joke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the entire article, especially the line at the end which states

> Get news satire from The Borowitz Report delivered to your inbox.

The article is satirical (and by satirical, I include non-factual, made-up, or, well, untrue, but intended to be so obviously untrue that nobody is fooled), and "Muslim Clockmakers" is a reference to the 14-year-old student arrested for bringing a homemade (well, repackaged; he didn't actually make it) digital clock to school.

The "quote" from Trump is fabricated.

Comment: Sure it's satire, but it speaks volumes that the Trump "quote" is just ... so plausible.

Comment: @DanBron It's simply hard to be unambiguously satirical when it comes to Trump...